# Why are Hogwarts' students so ignorant of Muggle society?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Before going to Hogwarts young wizard and witches must have either gone to Muggle school or been home schooled. Probably not every pair of wizard parents wants or has the time to home school their children. So if they went to Muggle school, how could they be so ignorant about the Muggle society when they are surrounded by it almost every day of their lives? It would be impossible not to learn how to use daily things like computers and electric lights if they were exposed to that type of environment. The only alternative is that wizard and witch children have no education at all up until the age of eleven...but to not have any experience with school and then be sent away to boarding school for ten months? That is inconceivable to me. Any ideas?

Comment: "Probably not every pair of wizard parents wants or has the time to home school their children. So if they went to Muggle school" - sorry but that seems like an unwarranted assumption largely contradicted by canon.

Comment: According to JKR, most of them are home-schooled (http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11745/3567) to avoid them blabbing about magic.

Comment: @alexwlchan - Dupe, surely?

Comment: @Richard - I think so.