# How do wizards do primary education?

Tags: harry-potter

If Hogwarts admits children from 11, who takes care of primary education?

I would imagine lots of anti-social, semi-literate people if parents are left to their devices in educating their children. But then the government does taxpayer-funded universal education with Hogwarts and depends on a society of educated people. So where are the primary schools?

Comment: @b_jonas yes it is. Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11745/4918